# Handling Input validation in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, data-binding

I am very new to angularjs and I just cant figure out how I would go about validating my inputs.

I have an input which should never be empty. The model will always have a value. Whenever a user inputs invalid data (i.e nothing or maybe invalid characters) I would like the input to revert to its original value.

For instance, If the initial value was `50` and I deleted all of that (or entered text) and deselected the input, I would expect the input's value to change back to `50`.

Here is my controller:

```
var MyController = null;
app.controller("MyController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.data = myData;
    $scope.validate = function(value, oldValue) {
        if(!value || value == "") {
            // Do something after validation
            value = oldValue;
        }
        // Our value should be valid now (either replaced or changed)
    }
    MyController = $scope;
}]);
```

And my HTML (i would rather not have to type `data.something` twice if possible):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.something" ng-change="validate()" />
```

**Small Clarification**: If the value of the input is "50" and a user removes the "0", the input would be at "5" which is valid. However if the user adds a "x" after I **DONT** want the input to change, it should still be at "5". However if all the input is empty, I would like `onBlur` for the original value to be placed back into the input and the model unchanged.

Comment: There is (at least) one tricky detail: say "50" is valid, as well as "5", but "5x" isn't (e.g. a numeric input). The user focuses the input while it contains "50", deletes the trailing zero (now it contains "5" - still valid) and then appends "x" and focuses out. Noe the input contains "5x" - invalid. What value should the input revert to?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Look at my updated Answer with a clarification, sorry for the confusion again.

Comment: Why not HTML5? 
`<input type="text" ng-model="data.something" ng-change="validate()" required="required" />`

Comment: @Baruch This is not a form. To my knowledge that is only checked when the form is submitted.

Comment: Some alternatives that may be helpful: the built-in [forms stuff](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) supports validation incl the new html5 input types and attributes, and additionally [`ng-pattern`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern) may also be helpful.

Comment: @Jeroen Wow, i didnt know about `ng-pattern`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you need ng-blur and probably ng-focus:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.something" ng-focus="store()" ng-blur="revertIfInvalid()"/>

$scope.store = function() {
  $scope.stored = $scope.data.something;
}

$scope.revertIfInvalid= function() {
  if (!$scope.data.something) {
    $scope.data.something = $scope.stored;
  }
}
```

This will work, but to make it reusable, you then want to make directive for this, like:

```
app.directive('fancydirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(sc, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      var stored;
      elem.on('focus', function() {
        sc.$apply(function() {
          stored = ngModelCtrl.$modelValue;
        });
      });
      elem.on('blur', function() {
        sc.$apply(function() {
          if (ngModelCtrl.$invalid) {
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(stored);
            ngModelCtrl.$render();
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/fiRKS765Kyh6ikRqc8if?p=preview

Comment: This works perfectly, however is there a way I can add further validation (like allowing only text)? So, if I was to press "0" in this case, nothing would happen and the model data wouldn't change.

Comment: @HunterMitchell You can add validation logic inside the `elem.on('blur', ...)`. Maybe add an if statement that tests a regex that returns false if there's any character that's not a word character.

Comment: @Baruch that makes sense. Could I also do validation within `elem.on('change', ...)` to validate even further (i.e. remove any numbers as they are typed)

Comment: @Hunter, as u see in this directive there is a check for valid - so you can add any other validator like ng-pattern or custom.